# Does a discarded then cast card with madness count as discarded?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Play goes like this:

I have [Faith of the Devoted](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFaith%20of%20the%20Devoted%5d) and [Anje Falkenrath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnje%20Falkenrath%5d) on the field.

- I discard an [Anje's Ravager](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnje%27s%5d%2b%5bRavager%5d) via [Anje Falkenrath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnje%20Falkenrath%5d)'s tap ability.
- For this creature I pay its madness cost and place it on the field.

Does [Faith of the Devoted](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFaith%20of%20the%20Devoted%5d)'s ability trigger?

What confuses me is what [this page on the Discard keyword](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Discard) says:

> Discard is an evergreen keyword action which takes cards from a player's hand and puts them in their graveyard.

But the fact is that a creature with madness never hits the graveyard! Instead, it goes to exile, then to the battlefield.

So I'm not completely sure whether the discard ability on [Faith of the Devoted](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFaith%20of%20the%20Devoted%5d) should trigger on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that still counts as discarding a card. The Madness ability is defined in [702.34a](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Madness):

> Madness is a keyword that represents two abilities. The first is a static ability that functions while the card with madness is in a player’s hand. The second is a triggered ability that functions when the first ability is applied. “Madness [cost]” means “**If a player would discard this card, that player discards it, but exiles it instead of putting it into their graveyard**” and “When this card is exiled this way, its owner may cast it by paying [cost] rather than paying its mana cost. If that player doesn’t, they put this card into their graveyard.”

The card is still discarded, and the Madness ability changes where it goes.